# Recommended approach for integrating a CDN with a Craft site

Tags: performance, cdn

I realize there are lots of options out there, but I’d be interested to know what service folks would recommend for integrating a CDN with Craft?

It'd also be helpful to know what the general pain points, strengths and/or weaknesses of a given approach are (especially as it relates to Craft integration).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 1) it's not Craft-specific, would be better off on ServerFault/Stack Overflow. 2) It's quite a broad, opinionated topic.

Comment: Voting to reopen, question has been rewritten to be more specific and Craft-based.

Comment: I'm voting you two settle it in a cage match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's extremely easy if you're using a pull CDN like MaxCDN or KeyCDN. You just point your CDN at your server, and then point your Asset Sources at your CDN.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. It seemed like it should be a fairly trivial task, but I wasn't sure if I was missing some major blind spot I just wasn't aware of.